# Conditionally insert a piece of Django template with HTML code into my template using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-templates

I am trying to create a template with Django to use with all the pages I have in my project. All the pages display similar tables which makes it easier but some of them require an extra check or two. So in writing this one-size-fits-all template, I would like to have this piece of code if it is one type of page:

```html
    {% if not package_check %}
    <p style="color:red">Package not found, so script did not run. Install package and try again</p>

    {% elif count|length %}
     <!-- rest of html template -->
    {% endif %}
```

Otherwise, I would like to have this piece of code:

```html
    {% if count|length %}
    <!-- rest of html -->
    {% endif | length %}
```

Since they are very similar I am wondering if it's possible (and how can I do it) to insert it into the HTML with Javascript when loading the page and make it test for the Django variables in the template tags.

Answer (score 0):

You want to insert a new template or create a new html element from javascript

if you want include new template

you can do this

```
{% if not package_check %}
    <p style="color:red">Package not found, so script did not run. Install package and try again</p>

    {% elif count|length %}
     <!-- rest of html template -->
    {% include 'youranothertemplate.html' %}
    {% endif %}
```

create new element from javascript

```js
const newElement = document.createElement("h1")
newElement.innerText = "Hai"
document.getElementById("new").append(newElement)
```

```html
<div id="new">

</div>
```

Comment: Depending on the request page, I want my template to load with the first piece of script in my original post or the second one, the rest of the template should be the same for both. I'm trying to avoid having multiple templates since 99% of the code is the same

Answer (score -1):

Nothing understandable. Try to write clear.